# Key press Filter search on a field it work's in classic but not in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning, multi-select

When we have Hundred of values in picklist it's difficult and time consuming for user to scroll down and search there value, so with the help of Keypress on keyboard that cursor reaches the initial filter of that value from(A-Z), This thing works in the salesforce classic but not in salesforce lightning, How to enable or code this functioning in salesforce lightning

[image]

As Above you can see we have Multi-Picklist field here we are in classic when we press any key on keyboard

[image]
For E.G. if User press 'G' on keyboard in second image cursor will reach to the field starting with 'G'
[image]
But in lightning it does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the known **Idea** : [Lightning multi-select picklist quick jump to values using keyboard](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXqmUAF/lightning-multiselect-picklist-quick-jump-to-values-using-keyboard)

You might want to upvote it so that it gets more attention